# Cannot import image in NextJs project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm converting a previus React.js website to a Next.js one, followed the guide on converting create react-app to a next-app.

An image is imported for usage inside a html vanilla `<img>` tag, in order to use tailwind classes. Followed some tutorials on the matter and they advised installing `next-images` and configuring `next.config.js` with the following code

```
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
 esModule: true
})
```

This is the error thrown at runtime

```
./components/partials/Features.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '/images/features-bg.png'
  1 | import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
  2 | import Transition from '../utils/Transition.js';
> 3 | import FeaturesBg from '/images/features-bg.png';
  4 | import FeaturesElement from '/images/features-element.png'
  5 | import Image from 'next/image';
  6 |
```

The folder structure I'm using follows the create next-app example, with a `public` folder containing all static files. I created an `images` folder inside it and verified that there are no typos in the filename. Full repository is available [here](https://github.com/diogoneiss/nextJsCurriculum)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed the  `import FeaturesBg from '/images/features-bg.png'` to `const FeaturesBg = '/images/features-bg.png'` and nextjs relative `/public` static imports worked.

Answer (score 0):

In next js you should give the address of your image to src of img tag , you shouldn't import it ,
like this `<img src="/images/features-element.png" alt="" />`

Answer (score 0):

The specified path is incorrect. In your case it'd be `../../public/images/filename.png`.

If you're not sure why you used `next-images` package, perhaps, you don't need it. Just add images to `public` and reference it as @m.hedayat suggested.

Comment: Next.js uses a absolute path to /public folder at runtime, the next-app uses it.
The package was supposed toallow react like imports, I don't know why it doesn't work. Gonna open a issue on npm

Comment: @DiogoNeiss, it does but not for importing Node modules. You need either specify correct path during build time or let the browser load images from `/public`, without `next-images`. At the moment, you combined two different approaches.